# loading jquery google chrome - strange error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a problem with jquery and google chrome current version.

i just this bit of code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

and in the console i got

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Im just loading jquery. why this error. in firefox no problem.

**Edit:
Got the error. on this pc is a script blocker active....**

Comment: I've tried it and I don't get the error in the console.

Comment: If you are not on a server you have to specify the protocol `http://` or `https://` and not just `//`

Comment: Are you calling somewhere else a jquery function? I think you forgot the `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Might be an extension you have installed in Chrome.

Comment: Does it fail in incognito mode?

Comment: In the console you could see on the right side the file where the error is coming from. Click on the file and see where the error is coming from.

Comment: @Johnride your right... there is a script blocker addon (this happens when you work on a differnt pc because yours is broken). thanky you